# How to get a date to the end of week in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a field called `delDate` and I want to use `project` to get the end of the week which is next Saturday and I want to use the end of week to group the `revenue`/ How do I do this in MongoDB?

```
weekEnd: {
  $subtract: [{
    $dateFromParts: {
      "year": { $year: "$$NOW" },
      "month": { $month: "$$NOW" },
      "week": { $add: [{ $week: "$$NOW" }, 1] },
    }
  }, 86400000]
}
```

Comment: Do you want the previous Saturday or coming Saturday? please add the expected output.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar Next Saturday

Comment: What should happen it's Saturday today ?

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar if it's saturday today, then the date will be today.

Comment: Cool, it should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/ID0P83Au0ul

This Will get you next Saturday

> Today + days for next Saturday

> 7 is Saturday, so 7 - today's day number * 1 day time

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      weekEnd: {
        $add: [ "$$NOW", { "$multiply": [ 86400000, { "$subtract": [ 7, { $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" } ] } ] } ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

**Update**

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/eGpsaGNTvJ_

Next Saturday without time

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$addFields":{
    weekEnd:{
      $dateFromString:{
        dateString:{
          $dateToString:{
            format:"%Y-%m-%d",
            date:{$add:["$$NOW",{"$multiply":[86400000,{"$subtract":[7,{$dayOfWeek:"$$NOW"}]}]}]}}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

If you want to use node.js

You can use `moment().startOf('isoWeek').day("saturday");`